# Making a dict of a list with more then 1 value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am a rookie at python, having a hard time figuering out how lists and dict really works. In my program i have a list that looks like:

```
Hat =[334,hat,59,200]
```

that i want to make into a dict, with a key `334` and the vaule = `[hat,59,200]`. How could i make it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply extract the first and all further elements with a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
{Hat[0]: Hat[1:]}
```

If you had multiple hats, you can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
hats = [
    [334,'hat',59,200],
    [123,'chapeau',19,300],
    [999,'hut',1,100],
]

print( {Hat[0]: Hat[1:] for Hat in hats} )
```

Comment: Wow did not realize that slice was such a powerful tool, but what if i have a list of several objects (lets say the Hat is just 1 object in a list of several objects). If i would use sliceing, would that apply for each line (given that i use a for loop to go through each line)?

Comment: @RickardSturesson Updated the answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you! Would you plz look at my edited version, since it involves a more complicated problem? Think I am getting the hang of it, but not sure

Comment: @Bardolf Sorry, but when you add multiple additional questions, you make it hard to follow questions and answers, and your question becomes hard to read for others. Instead, just [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If necessary, you can link to this one. Thanks!